# What do you call a pathway or hole made in a hedge or undergrowth by the track of an animal?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, etymology

What is the word for a hole of pathway made by an animal in the hedgerow or undergrowth?

Comment: A spoor:  a track or trail, esp. of a wild animal.

Answer (score 1):

*Smeuse* is one word, though given you're asking just days after [*Landmarks* by Robert Macfarlane](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/feb/27/robert-macfarlane-word-hoard-rewilding-landscape) was published, you might already know that.

Comment: Smeuse! Fantastic - my husband heard it on the radio - presumably discussing Landmarks by Robert Macfarlane - but we couldn't locate the word. Thanks so much.